# $.delay() and setTimeout() issue in javascript/jQuery. Which will win?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, delay, fade

This is a small javascript/jQuery program where the user starts with a portfolio of 20K and, when one inputs an amount and clicks on 'buy', the program then evaluates if you have enough money to do so. If you don't, then a message appears saying that you have insufficient funds. I want that message to stay on the screen for at least 5 seconds and, ideally, fadeout slowly afterwards. I've tried both the `$.delay()` method with jQuery and the `setTimeout()` method and both don't work. Any idea why?

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Some other code that works:

**JS :**

```
$("#buttonBuy").click(function() {
      amount= document.getElementById('investment').value

      if (/*you have enough money*/){
            //do something
     }
     else
     {

        //1st option (setTimeOut): it doesnt respect the delay for some reason,only shows up for about 1 sec
        document.getElementById('insufficientFunds').innerHTML= "Insufficient funds! "; 

        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById('insufficientFunds').innerHTML= "";   
        }, 5000);
    }
});

//2nd option (delay method) : I get error--> Failed to execute 'query SelectorAll on element: *;x is not valid selector

   $(function () {
           $('#insufficientFunds').fadeIn('slow', function () {
              $(this).delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
           });
    });
};
```

**HTML :**

```
<form>
    <input  type="text" id="investment"  <br>
    <button id="buttonBuy" >Buy</button> 
</form>

<p>Portfolio Value :</p>
<p id="portfolio"></p>

//1st option
<p id="insufficientFunds"> </p>

//second option
<p hidden id="insufficientFunds" > insufficient funds! </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't repeat your error, but this code seems to be working.

```
$("#buttonBuy").click(function () {
    amount = document.getElementById('investment').value

    if (true) {

        $(function () {
            $('#insufficientFunds').fadeIn('slow', function () {
                $(this).delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
            });
        });
    };
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qrnar2mp/1/)

Comment: thanks that is appreciated :) it helped! for some reason when i switched this code into the if(true) statement rather than the else it worked! not rlly sure why but now its all good! thanks for helping . i appreciate it.

Comment: there's no point in wrapping something in `if (true) { .. }` since it will always execute...

Comment: @Rose, as @Crayon said, don't use the `if (true) {...}`. I just put it there because you didn't include any logic in the if statement. Also, please mark the answer as correct! :)